# App's Files folder accessible to another application

Tags: android, android-sharing, android-fileprovider

I have two apps that generate some files, I would like these files to be synchronized on a server. To avoid code duplication I'm creating only one background worker thread to synchronize these files. At this point I have two independent question:

1. Is it a good practice to have one worker thread synchronizing two applications's files on the server ?
2. Let's say the worker thread is in app1 how can app1 access app2's files ?

I made some research I've found that ContentProvider would be a good way to do it if I was using a Database.

Comment: 2.If the files are stored in external files dir or on sdcard they are readableby by all other apps.

Comment: No, the files are private, its stored in the app folder

Comment: What do you consider to be the app folder? You know there are several app folders?

Comment: data/package/files I retrieve the path via getFilesDir()

Comment: That is mostly /data/data/package/files. Other packages have no acces to FilesDir. So I would let handle the synchonization by the app itself.